# Complex Range Operation Help: Determining Available Time Ranges Given Schedules and a Requested Time

Tags: ruby, data-structures

So I am trying to build a Booking app and ran into some problems.

Basically I have a set of Appointments for a client:

```
appointments = [
    Mon, 29 Dec 2014 11:00:00 PST -08:00..Mon, 29 Dec 2014 12:30:00 PST -08:00,
    Mon, 29 Dec 2014 09:00:00 PST -08:00..Mon, 29 Dec 2014 10:30:00 PST -08:00,
    Mon, 29 Dec 2014 14:00:00 PST -08:00..Mon, 29 Dec 2014 15:30:00 PST -08:00
]
```

and then I book this time:

```
Mon, 29 Dec 2014 14:00:00 PST -08:00
```

which looks for a service offered that takes an hour and 30 mins so the time range I want to book is:

```
requested_time_range = Mon, 29 Dec 2014 14:00:00 PST -08:00..Mon, 29 Dec 2014 15:30:00 PST -08:00
```

and the available time for the day is:

```
full_time_range = Mon, 29 Dec 2014 07:30:00 PST -08:00..Mon, 29 Dec 2014 16:00:00 PST -08:00
```

Using the range_operators gem(https://github.com/monocle/range_operators), I am able to do this:

```
a1 = full_time_range - appointments.first
```

which will result to (range operation `-` results to an array of ranges):

```
[
    Mon, 29 Dec 2014 07:30:00 PST -08:00..Mon, 29 Dec 2014 10:59:59 PST -08:00,
    Mon, 29 Dec 2014 12:30:01 PST -08:00..Mon, 29 Dec 2014 15:00:00 PST -08:00
]
```

so looping through all appointments, and deducting them from the full_time_range , then formatting the array so we have a flat array, I come up with:

```
available_times = [
    Mon, 29 Dec 2014 07:30:00 PST -08:00..Mon, 29 Dec 2014 10:59:59 PST -08:00,
    Mon, 29 Dec 2014 12:30:01 PST -08:00..Mon, 29 Dec 2014 15:00:00 PST -08:00,
    Mon, 29 Dec 2014 07:30:00 PST -08:00..Mon, 29 Dec 2014 08:59:59 PST -08:00,
    Mon, 29 Dec 2014 10:30:01 PST -08:00..Mon, 29 Dec 2014 15:00:00 PST -08:00,
    Mon, 29 Dec 2014 07:30:00 PST -08:00..Mon, 29 Dec 2014 13:59:59 PST -08:00,
    Mon, 29 Dec 2014 07:30:00 PST -08:00..Mon, 29 Dec 2014 08:59:59 PST -08:00,
    Mon, 29 Dec 2014 10:30:01 PST -08:00..Mon, 29 Dec 2014 15:00:00 PST -08:00,
    Mon, 29 Dec 2014 07:30:00 PST -08:00..Mon, 29 Dec 2014 13:59:59 PST -08:00 
]
```

Now what I can't quite get is how to find if the `requested_time_range` is covered by the `available_times`. Most of the time it is not accurate because the requested_time_range is sometimes within one element of the available_times array, sometimes not.

Is there an accurate way to find out if `requested_time_range` is available in my case? (I think I have to do something about the available_times, but I don't know what

Answer (score 1):

You need to change your request_time_range to make its `max` be 1 second (or more) less than it currently is.

```
booking_time = some_time # "Mon, 29 Dec 2014 14:00:00 PST -08:00" in your case
# 5399.seconds equals (1.5.hours - 1.second )
request_time_range = booking_time..(booking_time + 5399.seconds)
```

Then the following **should** work:

```
available_times.any? do |time_range|
  (time_range.min <= requested_time_range.min) &&
  (time_range.max >= requested_time_range.max)
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I've had a fun time looking into doing this my own way...it may or may not be for you, and there are room for speed improvements, but here's what I came up with. You can integrate it to your situation however you wish.

EDIT: I also haven't tested this for all scenarios...

---

**range_comparison.rb**

```
####
## Use case: Are you available between Nov 19th and 30th?
## No, I'm only available between Dec 1st and 2nd
## 
## requested_dates = DateTime.parse("Nov 19, 2014")..DateTime.parse("Nov 30, 2014")
## available_dates = DateTime.parse("Dec 1, 2014")..DateTime.parse("Dec 2, 2014")
## p 'Dates intersect on: '
## p requested_dates.first_coincide_with(available_dates)
####

class Range
  def first_coincide_with(compared_range)
    # Barf if it's anything other than a Range
    raise(ArgumentError, 'Only Ranges are permitted!') unless compared_range.kind_of?(Range)
    # Find the closest starting point for searching
    min = [self.min, compared_range.min].max
    # Find the end time
    max = [self.max, compared_range.max].min
    # Quickly exit if they are completely out of bounds to one another
    return if min > max

    # Now start searching for first available unit
    # Hopefully they know to use this in a strictly Integer Range... :)
    pos = min
    until pos > max
      return pos if pos >= min
      pos += 1
    end
    nil
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is appointments are not an *inclusive* range. The end time should be excluded, so use `...` instead of `..` when building the ranges.

Imagine you have a `9 to 10:30` and a `10:30 to 12`. With inclusive ranges, you get a schedule that looks like:

```
|------|
       |------|
```

Instead of excluding the last value:

```
|------|------
```

With no overlap, checking that an array of ranges does not contain a new range, make sure that no range contains the start or end of the new range.

```
def include?(ranges, range)
  ranges.any?{ |r| r.cover?(range.begin) || r.cover?(range.end) }
end

def valid?(appointments, appointment)
  !include?(appointments, appointment)
end
```

Note the difference between [Range#include?](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Range.html#method-i-include-3F) and [Range#cover?](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Range.html#method-i-cover-3F). You want `cover?`.

**EDIT**: To find available times, sort the ranges and grab the non-zero gaps.

```
def available_ranges(ranges)
  pairs = ranges.sort_by(&:begin).each_cons(2)
  new_ranges = pairs.map do |r1, r2|
    r1.end...r2.begin
  end
  new_ranges.reject{ |r| r.begin == r.end }
end
```